# Mockito.when() not working in a unit test when mocking FeignCLient

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I have a Component class which looks like this:

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class OutboundSystemTriggeredDirectAnalyzer implements BufferAccountAnalyzer {

    private FeignCustomerClient customerClient;
 

    @Override
    public void analyze(BankStatementTransaction bankStatementTransaction) {
        CustomerSummaryResponseDto customerSummary = new CustomerSummaryResponseDto();
        CustomerSummaryBankAccountRequestDto parsedAccountNumber = CustomerUtils
                .parseAccountNumber(bankStatementTransaction.getAccountNumber());
        try {
            customerSummary = customerClient
                    .getCustomerSummaryByBankAccount(parsedAccountNumber).getBody();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error on getting customer summary for bank account: {}", parsedAccountNumber);
        }

 
        CustomerIdentity customerIdentity = null;
        if (customerSummary != null && customerSummary.getProducts() != null) {
            customerIdentity = CustomerUtils.identifyCustomer(customerSummary);
        }
}
```

The feign client is

```
@FeignClient(CUSTOMER_MANAGEMENT)
public interface FeignCustomerClient {
    

    @PostMapping(CUSTOMERS_PATH + SUMMARY + READ + BY_BANK_ACCOUNT)
    ResponseEntity<CustomerSummaryResponseDto> getCustomerSummaryByBankAccount(CustomerSummaryBankAccountRequestDto request);

}
```

I created a test

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class OutboundSystemTriggeredDirectAnalyzerTest {


    @Mock
    private FeignCustomerClient customerClient;
    @Mock
    private FeignOldtransactionClient transactionClient;
    @InjectMocks
    private OutboundSystemTriggeredDirectAnalyzer analyzer;

    @Test
    public void matchCustomer() {
        BankStatementTransaction bankStatementTransaction = new BankStatementTransaction();
        bankStatementTransaction.setAccountNumber("31-046-006770124");
        CustomerSummaryBankAccountRequestDto parsedAccountNumber = new CustomerSummaryBankAccountRequestDto(31, 46, "6770124");

        CustomerSummaryResponseDto customerSummary = new CustomerSummaryResponseDto();
        BaseProductDto baseProductDto = new BaseProductDto(ProductType.LENDER, ProductSubType.PRIVATE, 32L);
        List<BaseProductDto> baseProducts = new ArrayList<>();
        baseProducts.add(baseProductDto);
        customerSummary.setProducts(baseProducts);

        WithdrawSearchRequestDto withdrawSearchRequestDto = new WithdrawSearchRequestDto();
        withdrawSearchRequestDto.setIsApproved(TRUE);
        withdrawSearchRequestDto.setLenderId(32L);

        TransactionResponseDto transactionDto = new TransactionResponseDto();
        transactionDto.setAmount(new BigDecimal("2000.00"));
        List<TransactionResponseDto> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
        transactions.add(transactionDto);

        Mockito.when(customerClient.getCustomerSummaryByBankAccount(parsedAccountNumber)).thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok(customerSummary));
        Mockito.when(transactionClient.searchLenderWithdrawTransactions(1L, withdrawSearchRequestDto)).thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok(transactions));

        analyzer.analyze(bankStatementTransaction);

        assertThat(bankStatementTransaction.getBankTransactionType().getId(), is(9L));

    }

}
```

I expect when a call to customerClient.getCustomerSummaryByBankAccount is made to return the customerSummary object that I created in the test, but when I debug - it does not return the customerSummary, but it is Null.

Answer (score 0):

I see issue in `CustomerSummaryBankAccountRequestDto` class, because the input parameters should be equal for right work of Mocks, that means `CustomerSummaryBankAccountRequestDto` class doesn't contain `equals` and `hashCode` methods for correct behavior in `Mockito.when()` condition.

You can use `EqualsAndHashCode` annotation for class:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class CustomerSummaryBankAccountRequestDto {
   ...
}
```

**Note:**
Or if you have already implemented `equals` and `hashCode` methods(without Lombok), these methods work incorrect.